# Resizing LUKS partition when not using LVM

Tags: partitioning, luks

I previously had two partitions on my hard disk, /dev/sdb1 and /dev/sdb2. sdb1 was unencrypted and sdb2 is encrypted with LUKS. I deleted sdb1 and would now like to resize sdb2 to take the space previously occupied by sdb1. How do I do this without destroying my data?

Cryptsetup has option called resize. What does this do? Can I just use it to enlarge the LUKS container to take all the space on the disk, then open the container and resize the underlying ext4 filesystem as I would normally do? The problem with this is that I normally use gparted to do things like this but gparted doesn't support resizing LUKS and I don't know how to do it with other tools.

Answer (score 1):

Use gparted to *move* the partition all the way to the left, then you can use command line `parted` to resize the partition, then it sounds like you can use the `cryptsetup resize` option to enlarge the encrypted container, then finally `resize2fs` to enlarge the filesystem in it.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be possible to move LUKS partitions with gparted.

Comment: @Echows, that's odd.. it should at least be able to *move* it.. are you using the latest version?  Don't forget you have to unmount the encrypted container first, including cryptsetup close.

Comment: I'm using the version in Ubuntu 15.10 repository which seems to be 0.19.0. In the information window for the partition it simply says "Linux Unified Key Setup encryption is not yet supported". It basically doesn't let me do anything to the partition.

Comment: Perfect answer! Worked like a charm.\\


Of course the area has to be unmounted and unmapped by luksClose! \\  


First I booted into a different Linux. Then I enlarged with gparted (0.30.0 on Fedora27). GParted recognises the LUKS correctly \\

cryptsetup resize only works after mapping the device, see man page! and it works perfect. \\
finally do resize2fs on the device (represented by the mapping). Asks for a e2fsck first, fine! \\
brilliant work. no trouble. Encryption with LUKS is really easy. Thanks user psusi for the hints!

Answer (score 1):

KDE Partition Manager 2.2.0 can resize LUKS partitions, so you won't need to deal with partition sizes manually.

It is not packaged for Ubuntu yet, but you can try to compile kpmcore 2.2.0 and then partitionmanager 2.2.0 yourself (which is probably less risky than resizing partitions manually).

Or alternatively you can try some LiveCD's of distributions that have already packaged kpmcore/kde partition manager 2.2.0. E.g. [Neon](https://neon.kde.org/) which is based on Ubuntu LTS.

Answer (score 1):

GParted 0.28 (released on February 2017) adds support for resizing file systems inside open LUKS volumes.

Currently no Ubuntu release ships that version, but it is simple to install from source, as the packaged version of libparted2 is recent enough for it to work. A `apt-get build-dep gparted` would give you the dependencies needed (plus `apt-get install gnome-common` if you need to (re)generate the configure script).

[1] http://gparted.org/news.php?item=207