# Resizing an encrypted LUKS partition using the KDE Partition Manager

Tags: partitioning, kde, encryption, luks

Following an answer in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/700193/resizing-luks-partition-when-not-using-lvm) I tried resizing (with the KDE Partition Manager) a LUKS encrypted partition created during the installation of Ubuntu. 
I booted from a Linux live USB stick and followed the [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZwiyCC9gvHM), up to the step "decrypt the partition" (minute 1:02). My problem is that the KPM has an additional field "Name" to complete for the encryption step.

- Entering nothing results in an error.
- Entering my username (or any other string) results in the partition being mounted but not unencrypted and the KPM refuses to unmount the partition.

Can someone tell me what is required for the "Name" field?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot ? Edit your post with it, if so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Partition Manager is too old (most likely 1.2.1). You need version 2.2 or later for LUKS resize to work.

Name field is just a name where unencrypted LUKS device is mapped to, e.g. if you type "something" it will be mapped to /dev/mapper/something. So your username should have worked out too unless you typed LUKS passphrase incorrectly. But for resize support you need newer version that actually generates this name for you automatically.

I suggest getting KDE Partition Manager 2.2 from some recent Live CD. Most of the other distros (except Debian, Ubuntu and their derivatives) come with a new version of KDE Partition Manager. I sometimes tried KaOS, Manjaro or Neon Live CDs for testing.